# LRANGE behaves in a very strange manner

Tags: redis

It seems as if I do not get the idea of this method (`LRANGE`). The situation is following. I've added in `Python` some data to two lists, one called `tables` and another one called `object_1_`. I pushed several items to list `tables` and only one item to list `object_1_`. I did it like so:

```
db.lpush('object_1_','some_data')
db.lpush('tables','some data')
...
...
db.lpush('tables','some data')
```

When I go to `redis-cli`, I see something which seems strange to me. I do the followng:

```
redis-cli> lrange object_1_ -1 0
some data
redis-cli> lrange tables -1 0
(empty list or set)
```

So, my question is why it is so? I try to understand why this construct `lrange key_name -1 0` returns something for one-element list and returns nothing for a larger list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of [`LRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/lrange)'s arguments is important - you've switched the `start` and `end` in your sample, try doing `lrange key 0 -1` ;)

Comment: What you are saying about order is right. But even if so, why does it still return something for one-element list and nothing for a larger list?

Comment: Interesting point which I had totally missed - thanks! The 2nd case behaves as expected but the 1st looks like a (minor) bug. I assume the different behavior is due to the different encodings used (ziplist vs linked list). I encourage you to report it directly by opening an issue in the github repository - http://github.com/antirez/redis/issues